# Ошибка: No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: java, android, android-studio

У меня есть проект с которым я работала на Mac (и там все было нормально), открыла этот же проект на Windows и получаю ошибки следующего содержания: 
`"Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value'@drawable/abs__btn_cab_done_pressed_holo_dark')."` В чем может быть проблема? Не загружены какие-то темы в `Android Studio`?

На всякий случай выкладываю build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        multiDexEnabled true

        resValue "string", "tray__authority", "com.example"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven'
        exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
        exclude 'NOTICE.txt'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile project(':abslib')
    compile project(':googleplayservices_lib')
    compile files('libs/recyclerview-21.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile files('libs/ksoap2.jar')
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    compile('net.grandcentrix.tray:tray:1.0.0-rc3') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
configurations { all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4' }
```

Так же выкладываю: `.gitignore`:

```
### Android template
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build

.idea/workspace.xml

# Built application files
.idea
*.apk
*.ap_

# Files for the Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files
*.log

# Android Studio Navigation editor temp files
.navigation/
```

Comment: Убедись что у тебя установленны SDK нужной версии в  SDK Manager

Comment: И выложи файлы  build.gradle

Comment: @KirillStoianov SDK нужной версии установлены

Comment: Я сначала подумал что это файл из самого Android нозможно действительно ? как уже сказали в ответе ниже может этого файло просто нету  в проекте Ты проверяла?

Comment: @KirillStoianov Судя по всему, файлы действительно потерялись при работе с git-ом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в папке `drawable` отсутствует файл `abs__btn_cab_done_pressed_holo_dark`. Если в проекте используется система контроля версий (Git или любая другая), то этот файл просто не был включен в индекс. Если это так, просто добавьте его в индекс и обновите проект. Такое может случаться если xml файлы добавлены в файл `.gitigone`. Ну в качестве временного решения можно просто скопировать этот файл с мака на windows в папку `drawable`.

Comment: Просмотрела .gitignore - не вижу, что бы xml файлы туда попадали

Comment: @Lucky_girl Ну как вариант это ручное добавление файла в папку. Потом его можно забыть добавить в индекс, особенно если работаете с git'ом через студию. У меня при коммите она не добавляет автоматически файлы которые были добавлены в ручную. Приходится искать его и добавлять самому. Если есть возможность, то откройте проект на маке и найдите его там. По идее он должен быть выделен красным цветом.

Comment: Судя по всему, все-таки придется копировать файлы